# Open Port 3306 in ubuntu 12.04 to allow connections to mysql from any ip

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a mysql server running on a server and I wanted to know how to Open a Port 3306 in ubuntu 12.04 to allow connections to mysql from any ip. Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Assuming iptables, and my memory is pretty hazy, but something vaguely like: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`.  Am not sure how safe opening your MySQL to the world is though.  Also, you're probably going to get better responses on superuser.se since it's a bit offtopic here.

Answer (score 16):

I Don't think firewall is your problem. Any modern mysql version has `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in its `my.cnf`, which makes it bind to loopback only. Comment it out, restart mysql and you should be good to go. Ubuntu doesn't have a restrictive firewall by default IIRC.

Comment: It's resolved my problem. The iptables hadn't been running.