# I can remotely connect to mySQL database in command line, but not with php script

Tags: php, mysql, remote-connection

The Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'tech'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in .......

I'm able to remotely connect in the command line, but not using php, any ideas where to look?

Here are the details:

Webserver A: 1.1.1.1 holds the php script:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $REGIS_DB_SERVER = "2.2.2.2"; //I've tried the IP as well as "pretendhostname.com"
    $REGIS_DB_NAME = "db_name";
    $REGIS_DB_USER = "tech"; // or any other user name
    $REGIS_DB_PASSWORD = "password";

    //connect to db
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host = $REGIS_DB_SERVER; dbname=$REGIS_DB_NAME; charset=utf8", $REGIS_DB_USER, $REGIS_DB_PASSWORD);
    print_r($db -> errorInfo());
    echo "Connected<br>";

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE Test(PersonID int,LastName varchar(255),FirstName varchar(255),Address varcha(255),City varchar(255))";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    echo "$result <be>";

?>
```

Webserver B: 2.2.2.2 holds the mySQL database:
Running Ubuntu 11.04

in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#Commented out to allow remote connections to this database
#bind-address           = 216.70.81.240
```

I run `mysql> select Host,User from user;` and get:

```
+-----------------------+------------------+
| Host                  | User             |
+-----------------------+------------------+
| %                     | root             |
| 127.0.0.1             | root             |
| 1.1.1.1               | tech             |
| localhost             | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost             | root             |
| localhost             | tech             |
+-----------------------+------------------+
```

[Open Port 3306 in ubuntu 12.04 to allow connections to mysql from any ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874518/open-port-3306-in-ubuntu-12-04-to-allow-connections-to-mysql-from-any-ip) implies it's not an iptable problem and to test out the connection:

I ssh-ed into Webserver A 1.1.1.1 and ran:

```
mysql -u tech -p -h 2.2.2.2
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 200672
Server version: 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: this looks like database permissions/privileges issue. You might want to double check your database permissions for this user from this host.

Comment: Notice that the error message says `tech@localhost`, not `tech@1.1.1.1`. It looks it's ignoring `host = $REGIS_DB_SERVER`.

Comment: I noticed this and it could be the reason why. I can't figure out why it's ignoring `mysql:host = $REGIS_DB_SERVER; `

am I missing a setting on Webserver A 1.1.1.1?

Comment: According to MYSQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html

It says:
If you have access problems with a Perl, PHP, Python, or ODBC program, try to connect to the server with mysql -u user_name db_name or mysql -u user_name -pyour_pass db_name. If you are able to connect using the mysql client, the problem lies with your program, not with the access privileges.

So I guess my PHP is wrong? The php script works for accessing local mySQL db though. It just seems to ignore the host= for remote databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding:
[PDO cannot connect remote mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630772/pdo-cannot-connect-remote-mysql-server)
I realized that if the host is not "understood", the PDO connection will default to host=localhost. Looking more closely, I realized there were 2 spaces between the assignment. I did not realize spaces mattered in the syntax.

So in the end, it was a syntax error:

The working solution (by removing spaces):

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$REGIS_DB_SERVER; dbname=$REGIS_DB_NAME; charset=utf8", $REGIS_DB_USER, $REGIS_DB_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 3):

you need disabled the  SELinux, for run the below CMD

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: +1.Thanks for your answer. It helped me i just upgraded my server from centos 6 to centos 8 and was struggling bcz of SELINUX

Comment: And add -P for persistence even after reboot. sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a database permissions/privileges issue. Ask your dba/sysad to `GRANT privileges` for your local server to access the database

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON db.* TO tech@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
I've tried the above replacing db with the database name and password with pw

Comment: Webserver A: 1.1.1.1 holds your php script.
Webserver B: 2.2.2.2 holds the mySQL database.
So, on Webserver B, you should run the command as 
`GRANT ALL ON db.* TO tech@'1.1.1.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`.

This is because, you are doing an ssh into 1.1.1.1 and then connecting to 2.2.2.2.
so the webserver B has to grant privileges on the server from where you are runnning the php, in this case 1.1.1.1

Comment: On webserver B, I opened mysql> and ran the suggested command. It returns `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)` 

Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I checked the mysql database on phpmyadmin, and in the user table, I see the 1.1.1.1 and tech host+user combo. All the priveleges seem to still be N. But I continue to be able to access remotely from command line, but not from the php script :(

EDIT- I can connect to a db in command line and run SQL queries. I think my best lead for the PHP is still the host ignoring part